# Infragistics WebDataGrid Find - can't find it

Tags: infragistics

I've recently started using this product.  The help on their site is lacking.

I have a WebDataGrid on a page.  I'm able to find the grid using $find(myGridID).  I'm able to access the columns using get_columns().

According to the docs I should be able to call

```
myGrid.get_columns().get_column(0).find("some text")
```

I get "object doesn't support..." etc.  So I did some digging and spit out all of the functions and properties and the find method isn't there.  So, again, according to the docs, I went to the grid object itself.  It has no find method either.  So, I'm stumped.

Any ideas?
Thanks
ST

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with a client side find method on the WebDataGrid.  What are you looking to accomplish?  What is it that you wish to find?